# Why are reserved keywords in Javascript not available as variable names?

Tags: javascript

For instance, "default" is a reserved keyword in Javascript, so I can't do this:

```
const default = 'does not work'
```

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/default), the "default" keyword is used for only two cases:

> switch statement and
>   export statement pages.

Is there a good reason, from a design or technical perspective, why it couldn't be unreserved for variables? I like to think that many of these reserved JavaScript keywords could be disambiguated based on the context in which the keyword is found, but not sure. Is it just a convenience thing or more that it is practically impossible because of "X"?

Comment: What do you mean, "from an engine perspective"? From an engine perspective, the reason not to do it is because you're implementing a language specification that says not to do it.

Comment: The down vote really necessary? @ChrisMartin " ... the reason not to do it is because you're implementing a language specification that says not to do it ... ". Imagine if everything in life were like that... I'm obviously looking for a more fundamental explanation here, but thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not just trying to be dismissive. I mean there are design rationales we can talk about, but they're from the *language design* perspective, and so I want to clarify what "engine perspective" means in your question. Are you asking why the makers of v8 chose to implement JavaScript instead of a new language that's slightly different from JavaScript?

Comment: @ChrisMartin I appreciate it. I don't think I'm coming at this from a language design perspective alone, because from that stand point, I would imagine that one could have many reasons for why it might be a good idea to have fully reserved words. Maybe I don't understand what language design entails, but I'm interested in any design or technical limitations that would make it impossible (i.e. disambiguation is impossible, therefore making parsing/interpretation impossible). I'm talking specifically about JavaScript and whether it could be implemented on v8 and others if the spec included it.

Comment: Maybe too many resources spent for disambiguation might be a valid concern also, I don't know... I'm just trying to get a sense of why the spec is the way it is in terms of reserved keywords.

Comment: Sometimes even if disambiguation is possible, you avoid requiring it because you want a programming language to be *easy* and *fast* to parse unabiguously, not merely *possible*. Because beyond executing the code, you also want to support things like a text editor being able to efficiently syntax-color it, on the fly, perhaps even in situations where a file contains syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's for practical reasons. Imagine you would be able to create variable

```
var false = 1;
```

and then use it

```
if(false) {...}
```

How is computer supposed to know what you mean (real *false* vs. your variable 1) ? That's why these words are *reserved*. System relies on them to have specific meaning

Comment: `Imagine you would be able to create variable

var false = 1;` - I believe that was actually possible in very early javascript - at least with `undefined` ... i.e. `var undefined = 1`, not sure about `true/false` or others

Comment: You certainly made a strong case for booleans, or any standalone keyword. So maybe those could be fully reserved, although I might still say that as long as you understand the consequences, it's fine. But this would not apply to the "default" keyword for instance which could be disambiguated much more easily based on its complimentary keywords, and their usage. In other words, is there any reason why the "default" keyword couldn't coexist in multiple contexts?